# Python: How can I check if a list contain a numeric value and return a boolean?

Tags: python, list

So lets say i have two lists

list1 = [1, "x", 3, "y", 5]

list2 = ["x",  "y", "x", "y"]

I would like a function that returns a boolean True for list1 because it contains a few ints and a boolean False for list2 because it contains only strings.

Comment: Try [any](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-any-function/amp/)

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_not_all_strings(lst):
    return not all(isinstance(k,str) for k in lst)
```

Or, depending on the need:

```
def contains_an_integer(lst):
    return any(isinstance(k,int) for k in lst)
```

Comment: Any might be better, if it's about the integers.

Comment: I think which one is more useful depends on the need, not on the data type. @infinitezero

Comment: @Burakhan Aksoy: "returns a boolean True for list1 because it contains a few ints"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture all kinds of numeric values, not just integers, you can use `numbers.Number`, like this:

```
import numbers

def has_numbers(items):
    return any(isinstance(item, numbers.Number) for item in items)
```

This will detect not just integers but also floats, decimals, fractions etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
def contains_num(l):
    return any(list(map(lambda x:isinstance(x,int),l)))
```

Comment: The `list` is unnecessary and will cause it to go through all the elements rather than stopping at the first number?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop. That way, you can return `True` once you find one integer and avoid iterating through the remaining elements.

```
def foo(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, int):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: `any` also avoids iterating through the rest of the elements once the answer is clear